# passing char array as argument to fopen

Tags: c

I am trying to open a file (on ubuntu) who's path is in a variable `path`. But when I try to pass path to `fopen()` it fails to find the file. 
Here is piece of code

```
char path="./client.c";
FILE *fp;
if((fp=fopen(path,"r"))==NULL)
printf("file could not be opened\n");
```

Nevertheless, if I directly pass the path it works fine. Following code works fine.

```
FILE *fp;
if((fp=fopen("./client.c","r"))==NULL)
printf("file could not be opened\n");
```

What am I doing wrong? How can i fix it?

Comment: Get it to compile -> `char path="./client.c";` should be `char* path="./client.c";`

Comment: You cannot pass arrays in C. But you do not have an array. Why do you ignore warnings?

Answer (score 2):

You are not declaring the array size in

```
char path="./client.c";
```

Change it to:

```
char path[]="./client.c";
```

Now your code should run as desired.

And if you are interested in using pointers use

```
const char* path="./client.c";
```

to point directly to the string

Comment: `char path` is not an array at all, it is not just the size missing.

Comment: "... (much more efficient than arrays) ..." Wrong. For a static array there is no difference; the array might even be faster on some architectures, as the value of the pointer need not be fetched.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
char path="./client.c";
```

with

```
const char* path="./client.c"; 
//^no array, just point to the string literal
```

if you don't need to modify the path.

If you do, then:

```
char path[]="./client.c";
//^create a modifiable array from the string literal
```

---

```
char path="./client.c";
```

compiles because a string literal autoconverts to the adress of the string literal 
(they're placed in a static, usually read-only, segment of your executable) which is an integer that can be, with a loss, assigned to a char.

However, you should absolutely get a warning about this from the compiler.

Aim for compilation without any warnings.

Comment: "a string literal autoconverts to the adress of the string literal" Well ... partly correct. The string literal is just an array and - as every array - it decays to a pointer to the first element for most usages. But where it is placed is irrelevant. It is just relevant that writes to it are UB.

Comment: @Olaf Yes, that's the point. Ed Heal suggested `char* path="./client.c";`, but there's a reason C++ doesn't allow this -- it should be with `const` because writing to string literals is UB.

Comment: 1) C is not C++ is not C. There is a reason C does allow it. It is the language which loads the gun if you want to shoot your foot . for good and for bad. 2) This is C, not C++. 3) In general, it depends on how OP wants to use that string. If she does not intend to change it, a `const char []` would be best (, fastest and most readable), but - as always - it depends

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the line

```
char path="./client.c";
```

with

```
char path[]="./client.c";
```

Comment: You should elaborate why that change is required.

Comment: the problem was \n at the end of path array. had to replace it with \0. now it works.

Comment: @saim2025: If your code is what you posted, **that** was not the actual problem. If you use a string literal, you do not need to append the terminator explicitly - unless the array is too small. But you did not even have an array, thus you just ignored a compiler warning (or use some stone-age compiler which does not warn).